# Empty String Check in Trigger

Tags: wpf

How can I check for an empty string in a trigger?

```
<Trigger Property="Source" SourceName="ControlName"  Value="">
     <Setter Property="Height" Value="0" TargetName="ControlName" />
</Trigger>
```

I have set the Height of the Control to 0 if the source of the imageControl is empty string or not set? How can I do it, Basically If the image is not set then I want to hide the image control in the template.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Kent is correct that the Source is not a string but if you do have a sting property to check against you can use the static String.Empty value:

```
Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}"
```

and the sys namespace declared as

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Comment: How could i use this in silverlight project , hence static is not supported in the silverlight

Comment: Thanks for the namespace declaration, this is what I needed :)

Answer (score 6):

If the property isn't set, its value will be `null`. To specify `null` in XAML you use a markup extension:

```
<Trigger Property="Source" SourceName="ControlName"  Value="{x:Null}">
     <Setter Property="Height" Value="0" TargetName="ControlName" />
</Trigger>
```

Comment: thanks for your comments , but I want to check for empty string, mean "" or string.Empty, how can I check it?

Comment: The `Source` property is not a `string`, it's an `ImageSource`, so what you're trying to do doesn't make sense.

Comment: Suppose that we have controls like textblock, label wich has content or Text property which is of type string. then how can we check?

Comment: Exactly as you were checking. I don't believe there's any need to explicitly specify `string.Empty`, but I could be wrong.